# error: expected expression before ‘double’. Can't get power function to work

Tags: c

I am making a basic program the will give you the interest rate of my loans after
a designated amount of years.  to do so, I need to use the power formula.

```
    totalLoanBalance = Double pow(interestRateAndPrincipal, yearsOutstanding) * LoansTaken;
```

but when I enter this information, I get this error

```
    error: expected expression before ‘double’
 totalLoanBalance = double pow(interestRateAndPrincipal, yearsOutstanding) * loansTaken;
                    ^
```

I have tried putting double in front of the variables in parentheses, and a few other strategies, but I can't seem to fix it.  I also don't grasp what the error is telling me.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This misunderstands the function calling syntax for C. You don't name the return type when you're calling a function. `totalLoanBalance = pow(...` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the return type of a function when you call it, only when it's defined or declared.

```
totalLoanBalance = pow(interestRateAndPrincipal, yearsOutstanding) * LoansTaken;
```

Comment: When i take out the double, I get this error message then                                             In function `main':
loans.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @DominicPelini That's because you didn't link in the math library, which is where `pow` resides.  Add `-lm` to the command line when compiling.

Comment: @DominicPelini Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.